# Where can I find good Introductory Adobe Flash CS3 tutorials and documentation for a beginner?

Tags: flash, documentation

I'm writing my first interactive animation in Flash CS3 and I'm having trouble locating some good references to teach me how to do it.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's the free way and there's the 'put your hand in your pocket' way :)

Free way is just to google what you're looking for. There's so much free information out there it's crazy.

The 'put your hand in your pocket' way is to go and buy yourself a beginners book.  I started by reading a few from the [friends of ed series](http://www.friendsofed.com/catalog.html).  They were a great introduction for me. Particularly have a look through the 'foundation' series on there, see if anything takes your fancy.  A book will make your learning a lot more structured which isn't a bad thing when you're first starting out.

Good luck